# Client side HTTP parameter pollution (reflected)

Tags: security

Some of my sites have been flagged by a security scanner as being vulnerable to client-side HTTP parameter pollution.  The security department says that this must be fixed.  How can I protect against this in WordPress?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

> **Issue detail**
>
> The name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter is copied into the response within the query string of a URL.
>
> The payload wzx&sfy=1 was submitted in the name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter. This input was echoed as wzx&sfy=1 within the "action" attribute of a "form" tag.
>
> This proof-of-concept attack demonstrates that it is possible to inject arbitrary query string parameters into URLs in the application's response.

> **Request**
>
> GET [removed]?wzx%26sfy%3d1=1 HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: [removed]
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
>
> Connection: close
>
> Referer: [removed]

> **Response**
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2020 00:44:05 GMT
>
> Server: Apache
>
> Link: <[removed]?p=35>; rel=shortlink
>
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31557600; preload
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> Content-Length: 28294
>
> Connection: close
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<hea
...[SNIP]...
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='gform_1' action='[removed]?wzx&#038;sfy=1=1'>
...[SNIP]...
```

Comment: Does this occur in many places? Do you know if this happens to correlate with forms associated with particular plugins or themes?

Comment: The affected form appears to be a Gravity Form. I suggest contacting them for support with this issue.

Comment: @mozboz This is a multisite installation.  Some of the subsites have Gravity Forms and some do not.  This issue is occurring on both types of sites